# Accessing Variables by Reference

Tags: variables, reference, swift

I am trying to figure out the basic way to reference a simple type in Swift.

In C, it's no issue:

```
int a = 42;
int* refA = &a;
*refA = 43;
// At this point, a is 43
```

In Swift, it seems that I can't do this.

```
var a:Int = 42

println ( a )

//    var aRef:Int = &a       // Nope.
//    var aRef:Int& = &a      // Nah.
//    inout var:Int aRef = &a // Nyet
//    var inout:Int aRef = &a // Non
//    var aRef:Int* = &a      // What are you, stupid, or stubborn?
//
//    aRef = 43               // If any of the above worked, I could do this.

println ( a )         // How can I get this to print "43"?
```

I can't find anything in the docs that say I can do this. I know about inout as a function parameter modifier, but I'd like to be able to do this outside of functions.

There's some basic reasons that I'd like to do this. Declaring classes of everything introduces some overhead (mostly planning and writing, as opposed to execution time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values cannot be passed by reference in Swift (except for inout parameters), this is one of the things that makes it "Objective-C without the C". You might have to rethink your approach with the possibilities and restrictions of the language in mind.

Comment: Well, you can pass by reference to functions (inout & works on value types), but it looks like you can't reference value types in the wild.

Comment: Exactly. Added the inout parameters exception for future reference. I'd like to add that using inout-parameters should probably only used when using Objective-C methods. In Swift there are more elegant ways.

Comment: I agree. A lot of learning Swift is learning new ways to do things. -Thanks!

Comment: `inout` is perhaps best used sparingly, but it can still be quite useful outside of C/ObjC-interoperable code. Look through the Swift standard library and you'll find several handy things you can do with it, like generic functions to sort any collection in place.

Comment: @rickster Interesting, will look into that! Do you happen to have a specific example in which i/o params are used in Swift's standard library?

Comment: `sort` and `swap` are good basic examples. In particular, `swap` is interesting in that, because of the way `inout` works, it'll swap whatever you pass to it, be those local variables, properties of a class, or even indexes in or slices of an array. Find more by opening the standard library interface in Xcode (cmd-click a library symbol like `String`) and searching for `inout`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, trying to use Language A as if it were Language B on a feature-for-feature basis is a good way to get yourself into round-peg-square-hole issues. Instead, step back a bit -- what problems do you solve using Feature X in Language B? Language A might have different (and even perhaps more elegant) ways to address those problems.

Not being able to create a pointer (or C++-style reference) to any arbitrary value is probably part of Swift's type/memory safety. Adding that level of indirection makes it harder for a compiler to make reasoned deductions about code (in particular, the ownership of memory addresses), opening all kinds of possibilities for undefined behavior (read: bugs, security holes).

Swift is designed to [eat bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift#Feeding). By using carefully-designed semantics for values vs. references, augmented with `inout` for specific uses, Swift can more carefully control memory ownership and help you write more reliable code. Without any loss in expressivity, really -- that expressivity just takes different forms. :)

If you really want to put a round peg into a square hole, you can cut down your "planning and writing" overhead with a single generic implementation that wraps any value in a reference. Something like this, maybe:

```
class Handle<T> {
    var val: T
    init(_ val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }
}
```

Note that with this, you still need to plan ahead -- since you can't create pointers/references to arbitrary things that already exist, you'll have to create something through a Handle when you want to be able to treat it like a reference type later.

And with some custom operator definitions, you might even be able to make it look a little bit like C/C++. (Maybe post on [Terrible Swift Ideas](http://terribleswiftideas.tumblr.com) if you do.)

Comment: Of course, you are absolutely correct. I always go through this phase when I'm learning new languages (You think SWIFT is tough? Try [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) -that was [a mind-bender](http://www.webmasterworld.com/xml/3326703.htm) for me). I'll get it, but I always have a few "throwaway" projects in a new language before I find my stride. I've [already completed a very simple app](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/nacc-ios-app), and I'm currently working on a much more complex one that involves remote PTP-IP and live video.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, your desired behavior is not all the difficult to achieve:

```
  1> func inc (inout x: Int) { x = x + 1 }
  2> var val:Int = 10
val: Int = 10
  3> inc(&val)
  4> val
$R0: Int = 11
```

What you loose is the 'performance' of a builtin binary operation; but what you gain by using functional abstraction well out weighs any non-builtin issue.

```
func incrementor (by: Int) (inout _ x: Int) { x = x + by }   #Bug in Swift prevents this '_'
var incBy10 = incrementor (10)
incBy10(&val)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the kind of overhead that I was trying to avoid. However, as stated previously, I am still thinking in a "C" world. I need to use Swift a bit longer to knock my thinking into the Swift Way. Luckily, I have a lot of PHP experience. PHP is a rather chaotic language, but it has many of the trapping that you'll find in Swift.

Comment: These days, worry about that level of overhead is probably over doing it - unless you already have a working, _correct_ application that you are now optimizing.  Even then, the optimization is not likely to be at the level of individual function calls vs builtin (assuming that even happens) but rather at the architecture (e.g. parallelism, communication paths) or algorithmic (e.g. searching, sorting) level.  If you are moving from PHP focus a bit of attention on Swift closures and currying.

Comment: Actually, I'm moving from ObjC and C++. I work in many different languages.

Comment: I'm curious. You have "Bug in Swift prevents this '_'", and I'm not sure what that means. I'm not so well-versed in Swift wildcards, and see them a lot, so I guess I still have plenty of homework ahead of me.

Comment: I fed your snippet into a playground, and, after a couple of tweaks (removing the wildcard and the comment, and adding a value var), it makes the parser on the Xcode 6 GMc crash. I raised a RADAR report on it. Xcode 6 GMc seems a bit less-than-stable. I keep getting intermittent parser and code formatter crashes. This is the first one that is 100% repeatable.